# Elasticsearch nested significant terms aggregation with background filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having hard times applying a background filter to a nested significant terms aggregation , the `bg_count` is always 0.

I'm indexing article views that have ids and timestamps, and have multiple applications on a single index. I want the foreground and background set to relate to the same application, so I'm trying to apply a term filter on the `app_id` field both in the boo query and in the background filter. `article_views` is a nested object since I want to be also able to query on views with a range filter on `timestamp`, but I haven't got to that yet.

**Mapping:**

```
    {
    "article_views": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            }
        }
    },
    "app_id": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
}
```

**Query:**

```
  {
   "aggregations": {
      "articles": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "article_views"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "articles": {
               "significant_terms": {
                  "field": "article_views.id",
                  "size": 5,
                  "background_filter": {
                     "term": {
                        "app_id": "17"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "app_id": "17"
               }
            },
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "article_views",
                  "query": {
                     "terms": {
                        "article_views.id": [
                           "1",
                           "2"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

As I said, in my result, the `bg_count` is always 0, which had me worried. If the significant terms is on other fields which are not nested the `background_filter` works fine.

**Elasticsearch version is 2.2.**

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be hitting the [following issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20101) where in your background filter you'd need to "go back" to the parent context in order to define your background filter based on a field of the parent document. You'd need a `reverse_nested` query at that point, but that doesn't exist. One way to circumvent this is to add the `app_id` field to your nested documents so that you can simply use it in the background filter context.

Comment: @Val Thanks, it seems like the right answer. If you want right it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be hitting the [following issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20101) where in your background filter you'd need to "go back" to the parent context in order to define your background filter based on a field of the parent document.

You'd need a `reverse_nested` query at that point, but that doesn't exist.

One way to circumvent this is to add the `app_id` field to your nested documents so that you can simply use it in the background filter context.